# Spark dataframe duplicate row based on splitting column value in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I have the following code in scala:

```
val  fullCertificateSourceDf = certificateSourceDf         
              .withColumn("Stage", when(col("Data.WorkBreakdownUp1Summary").isNotNull && col("Data.WorkBreakdownUp1Summary")=!="",                                                     rtrim(regexp_extract($"Data.WorkBreakdownUp1Summary","^.*?(?= - *[a-zA-Z])",0))).otherwise(""))
              .withColumn("SubSystem", when(col("Data.ProcessBreakdownSummaryList").isNotNull && col("Data.ProcessBreakdownSummaryList")=!="",                                         regexp_extract($"Data.ProcessBreakdownSummaryList","^.*?(?= - *[a-zA-Z])",0)).otherwise(""))
              .withColumn("System", when(col("Data.ProcessBreakdownUp1SummaryList").isNotNull && col("Data.ProcessBreakdownUp1SummaryList")=!="",                                         regexp_extract($"Data.ProcessBreakdownUp1SummaryList","^.*?(?= - *[a-zA-Z])",0)).otherwise(""))
              .withColumn("Facility", when(col("Data.ProcessBreakdownUp2Summary").isNotNull && col("Data.ProcessBreakdownUp2Summary")=!="",                                         regexp_extract($"Data.ProcessBreakdownUp2Summary","^.*?(?= - *[a-zA-Z])",0)).otherwise(""))
              .withColumn("Area", when(col("Data.ProcessBreakdownUp3Summary").isNotNull && col("Data.ProcessBreakdownUp3Summary")=!="",                                         regexp_extract($"Data.ProcessBreakdownUp3Summary","^.*?(?= - *[a-zA-Z])",0)).otherwise(""))
              .select("Data.ID",
                      "Data.CertificateID",
                      "Data.CertificateTag",
                      "Data.CertificateDescription",
                      "Data.WorkBreakdownUp1Summary",
                      "Data.ProcessBreakdownSummaryList",
                      "Data.ProcessBreakdownUp1SummaryList",
                      "Data.ProcessBreakdownUp2Summary",
                      "Data.ProcessBreakdownUp3Summary",
                      "Data.ActualStartDate",
                      "Data.ActualEndDate",
                      "Data.ApprovedDate",
                      "Data.CurrentState",
                      "DataType",
                      "PullDate",
                      "PullTime",
                      "Stage",
                      "System",
                      "SubSystem",
                      "Facility",
                      "Area"
                     )
                     .filter((col("Stage").isNotNull) && (length(col("Stage"))>0))
                     .filter(((col("SubSystem").isNotNull) && (length(col("SubSystem"))>0)) || ((col("System").isNotNull) && (length(col("System"))>0)) || ((col("Facility").isNotNull) && (length(col("Facility"))>0)) || ((col("Area").isNotNull) && (length(col("Area"))>0))
                      )
                     .select("*")
```

This dataframe fullCertificateSourceDf contains the following data:

[image: Original Data]

I have hidden some columns for Brevity.

I want the data to look like this:

[image: Target Data]

We are splitting on two columns: ProcessBreakdownSummaryList and ProcessBreakdownUp1SummaryList. They both are comma seperated lists.

Please note if the values in ProcessBreakdownSummaryList (CS10-100-22-10 - Mine Intake Air Fan Heater System, **CS10-100-81**-10 - Mine Services Switchgear) and ProcessBreakdownUp1SummaryList (CS10-100-22 - Service Shaft Ventilation, **CS10-100-81** - Service Shaft Electrical) are the same we should only split once.

However, if they are different as in ProcessBreakdownSummaryList(CS10-100-22-10 - Mine Intake Air Fan Heater System, **CS10-100-81**-10 - Mine Services Switchgear) and ProcessBreakdownUp1SummaryList (CS10-100-22 - Service Shaft Ventilation, **CS10-100-34** - Service Shaft Electrical) it should split again for a third row.

Thank you in advance for your help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve it many ways, I think the easiest approach for complicated processing is to use scala. You can read all columns including "ProcessBreakdownSummaryList" and "ProcessBreakdownUp1SummaryList", compare their values for being same/different and emit multiple rows for a single input row. Then flatmap on the output to get a dataframe with all rows you need.

```
val fullCertificateSourceDf = // your code

fullCertificateSourceDf.map{ row =>
val id = row.getAs[String]("Data.ID")
... read all columns

val processBreakdownSummaryList = row.getAs[String]("Data.ProcessBreakdownSummaryList")
val processBreakdownUp1SummaryList = row.getAs[String]("Data.ProcessBreakdownUp1SummaryList")

//split processBreakdownSummaryList on ","
//split processBreakdownUp1SummaryList on ","
//compare then for equality 
//lets say you end up with 4 rows.

//return Seq of those 4 rows in a list processBreakdownSummary
//return a List of tuple of strings like List((id, certificateId, certificateTag, ..distinct values of processBreakdownUp1SummaryList...), (...) ...)
//all columns id, certificateId, certificateTag etc are repeated for each distinct value of processBreakdownUp1SummaryList and processBreakdownSummaryList

}.flatMap(identity(_)).toDF("column1","column2"...)
```

Here is an example of splitting one row into multiple

```
    val employees = spark.createDataFrame(Seq(("E1",100.0,"a,b"), ("E2",200.0,"e,f"),("E3",300.0,"c,d"))).toDF("employee","salary","clubs")

    employees.map{ r =>
      val clubs = r.getAs[String]("clubs").split(",")
      for{
        c : String <- clubs
      }yield(r.getAs[String]("employee"),r.getAs[Double]("salary"), c)
    }.flatMap(identity(_)).toDF("employee","salary","clubs").show(false)
```

The result looks like

```
+--------+------+-----+
|employee|salary|clubs|
+--------+------+-----+
|E1      |100.0 |a    |
|E1      |100.0 |b    |
|E2      |200.0 |e    |
|E2      |200.0 |f    |
|E3      |300.0 |c    |
|E3      |300.0 |d    |
+--------+------+-----+
```

Comment: Thank you Salim. An example will be much appreciated.

Comment: please checkout the example provided.

Comment: Thats Great @Salim. how would you handle this (with null) ` val employees = spark.createDataFrame(Seq(("E1",100.0,"a,b"), ("E2",200.0,"e,f"),("E3",300.0,"c,d"),("E4",300.0, null))).toDF("employee","salary","clubs")`

Comment: Please avoid null for numeric columns, scala doesn’t recognize null for long. Rather use option or default value for numeric values. For string you can use null or a default value. I can crank an example for you if ask another question or upvote this one.